# 任意の引数（std::env:args()）を数値として受け取り関数に渡すには？

Tags: rust

現在Redditから拾ってきた任意の範囲の素数を漏れなく求めるプログラムを自分なりに改良しています。
そこで気になったのが、`std::env::args()`が文字リテラルを生成してしまう点です。

#### 伺いたいこと

このようなコードがあった場合、どのようにして、引数を取らせばよいのでしょうか？

```
fn t_or_f(x1: i64, ps1: &Vec<i64>) -> bool {
    for p1 in ps1 {
        if p1 * p1 > x1 {
             break; 
        } else if x1 % p1 == 0 {
             return false; 
            }
    }
    true
}
fn prime(n1: i64) {
    let mut ps2 = vec![2];
    let mut x2 = 3;
    while x2 <= n1 {
        if t_or_f(x2, &ps2) {
            ps2.push(x2);
        }
        x2 += 2;
    }
    println!("{:?}", ps2);
}

fn main() {
   prime(100); //ここの関数prime()に任意の数nを受け取らせるギミックを施したい。
}
```

いつもは`std::env::args()`で解決した問題でしたが、今回はprime()が`i64`整数を取るため悩んでいます。

#### 追記

回答者様のアドバイスを適用してみた所、`cargo test`は問題なく通りましたが、`cargo test 100`を実行してみた所以下のようなエラーで異常終了してしましました。

**現時点のコード**

```
fn t_or_f(x1: i64, ps1: &Vec<i64>) -> bool {
    for p1 in ps1 {
        if p1 * p1 > x1 {
             break; 
        } else if x1 % p1 == 0 {
             return false; 
            }
    }
    true
}
fn prime(n1: i64) {
    let mut ps2 = vec![2];
    let mut x2 = 3;
    while x2 <= n1 {
        if t_or_f(x2, &ps2) {
            ps2.push(x2);
        }
        x2 += 2;
    }
    println!("{:?}", ps2);
}

fn main() {
    let arg: String = std::env::args().next().unwrap();
    let p: i64 = arg.parse().unwrap();
   prime(p);
}
```

`cargo test`の内容

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s                                                                           
     Running target\debug\deps\viewp-a9faf854653fbc3d.exe

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

`cargo run 100`の内容

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
     Running `target\debug\viewp.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\libcore\result.rs:999:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\viewp.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

`RUST_BACKTRACE=1`を適用した結果

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target\debug\viewp.exe 100`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\libcore\result.rs:999:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:94
   1: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:94
   2: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:94
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:58
   4: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:58
   5: std::panicking::default_hook
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:215
   6: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:478
   7: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:385
   8: std::panicking::rust_begin_panic
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:312
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libcore\panicking.rs:85
  10: core::result::unwrap_failed<core::num::ParseIntError>
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\src\libcore\macros.rs:16
  11: core::result::Result<i64, core::num::ParseIntError>::unwrap<i64,core::num::ParseIntError>
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\src\libcore\result.rs:798
  12: viewp::main
             at .\src\main.rs:25
  13: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<()>
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\src\libstd\rt.rs:64
  14: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\rt.rs:49
  15: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\rt.rs:49
  16: panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libpanic_unwind\lib.rs:92
  17: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:276
  18: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:276
  19: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:276
  20: std::rt::lang_start<()>
             at /rustc/9eac386342c601b14311b435f2b6d314fc817bb5\src\libstd\rt.rs:64
  21: main
  22: invoke_main
             at d:\agent\_work\4\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  23: invoke_main
             at d:\agent\_work\4\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  24: BaseThreadInitThunk
  25: RtlUserThreadStart
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\viewp.exe 100` (exit code: 101)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

追記に対する回答です。[Argsのドキュメント](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html)に

> The first element is traditionally the path of the executable, but it can be set to arbitrary text, and may not even exist. This means this property should not be relied upon for security purposes.

とあるので、0番目の要素ではなく1番目の要素をとればいいかと思います。

```
fn main() {
    let arg: String = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
    let arg: i64 = arg.parse().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまで無事解決しました。ご協力に感謝します

Answer (score 0):

[String::parse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse) を使うことで文字列を整数に変換できます。

```rust
fn main() {
    let arg: String = std::env::args().next().unwrap();
    let arg: i64 = arg.parse().unwrap();
}
```